# Convert date from datetime to text in JPA Query

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa, sql-like

I want to find data from a table, using a "like" on date. I was get right result when execute this command

`SELECT * FROM transaction_history th WHERE date(th.transaction_date) LIKE '%7%';`

But when in JPA native query I got error like this

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ":"
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: `LIKE` is for string values. Would you expect `LocalDate.indexOf("7")` to work in Java? That's the equivalent to your SQL query.  What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve? Get all dates in "July"? Get all dates of the 7th day of the month? Get all dates that contain a "7" in their year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to postgresql [official doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-formatting.html), first of all u have to cast date column to string and after run your select query

> to_char(timestamp, text)  convert time stamp to string
> to_char(current_timestamp, 'HH12:MI:SS')

Is supposed to be smth like this:

```
SELECT * FROM transaction_history th WHERE to_char(th.transaction_date, 'HH12:MI:SS') LIKE '%7%';
```